# Does DroneCast infringe on this IP (US 3683530 A)?

Tags: patent-infringement, us3683530

Checkout http://dronecast.us
They use quadcopters to display vinyl banners with illuminated LEDs on the drone

Answer (score 1):

No. In fact it is impossible to infringe this patent in this century. It would have expired in 1992.